# Parameter object within R package

Tags: r

I have a simulation model that takes parameters.

Instead of passing all parameters to a main function (which is complicated for the user since the dimensions of some of the parameters depend on themselves, e.g. if `n=2`, `vec_n` is length 2), I wanted an internal PARAMETERS object within the package, which all functions could access, and the users can change.

I made a package `Test` with two functions and an internal list `INTERNAL=list(a=2)` which is saved in sysdata.rda.

```
test_function<-function(b){
  INTERNAL$a = b
  print(INTERNAL)
  second_function()
}

second_function<-function(){
  print(INTERNAL$a)
}
```

However on loading the package, and running it I get the following output:

```
> test_function(5)
$a
[1] 5

[1] 2
```

Clearly, the object itself doesn't change outside the function.

I'd appreciate any help / advice in getting this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INTERNAL$a = b` creates a local copy of `INTERNAL` in your function, and modifies that.  Since you want to modify the global copy, you could use

```
INTERNAL$a <<- b
```

but this is a bad idea, and probably wouldn't work in a package:  you can't modify most values in a package after it is installed.

Alternatives to this are to make `INTERNAL` into an environment (which you can modify), or create a function that returns the values you want, e.g.

```r
    INTERNAL <- function(a = "default", b = "default") {
      list(a = a, b = b)
    }

    INTERNAL(a = 2)
#> $a
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "default"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

You can combine these two ideas:

```r
INTERNAL <- local({
    saved <- list(a = "default", b = "default")
    function(...) {
      saved <<- modifyList(saved, list(...))
      saved
    }
})
INTERNAL(a = 1)
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "default"
INTERNAL(b = 2)
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 2
INTERNAL(c = 3)
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you that works. Is there any reason not to use an environment? It seems to work exactly as I want.

Comment: As long as you know what you're doing, environments are fine.  In fact, that's what my second solution is using:  it's just not making the environment obvious.